# Tkinter Insert outputting as [list] after "".join()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a python program that converts numbers to binary with a tkinter GUI. When using e.insert on a entry it will return a normal string:
0101010011
as
[0, 1, 0, 1...]

The function which converts a number to binary. I am aware the bin() alternative exists, I just wanted to create my own.

```py
def dec2bin(decnum):
  binarylist = []
  while (decnum > 0):
    binarylist.append(decnum % 2)
    decnum = decnum // 2
  binarylist.reverse()
  binarylist = str(binarylist)
  return "".join(binarylist)
```

The function that is called when a button in the tkinter gui is pressed which is intended to replace one of the entry box's text with the binary output.

```py
def convert():
  decimal = entrydec.get()
  decimal = int(decimal)
  entrybin.delete(0, END)
  entrybin.insert(0, dec2bin(decimal))
```

I expect the output of 010101, but the actual output is [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

Comment: Have you verified that `dec2bin(decimal)` is returning what you're assuming it's returning?

Comment: You are correct, it is not entry that is the problem. There must be an error in my code making it output a list instead of a string. Do you happen to see anything that I am not?

Comment: The first thing you should do is examine every variable after you set it or change it.

Comment: you have to use `str()` in `binarylist.append(str(decnum % 2))`, not in `binarylist = str(binarylist)`

Comment: @furas Thanks, you should make that the answer it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `str()` on list - `str([0, 1, 0, 0])` to get list with strings - `["0", "1", "0", "0"]`

You can use list comprehension:

```
    binarylist = [str(x) for x in binarylist]
```

or `map()` :

```
    binarylist = map(str, binarylist)
```

Or you have to convert numbers `0` ,`1` to string when you add to list:

```
    binarylist.append(  str(decnum % 2)  )
```

And later you can use `join()`

```
def dec2bin(decnum):
    binarylist = []

     while (decnum > 0):
        binarylist.append( str(decnum % 2) ) # <-- use str()
        decnum = decnum // 2

    binarylist.reverse()
    #binarylist = str(binarylist) # <-- remove it

    return "".join(binarylist)

dec2bin(12)
```

Result:

```
"1100"
```